# Laravel 4 Datatable Integration

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-4, datatable

I am new in Laravel and I want to generate MYSQL data using Laravel datatable, I did as follow:

This is my html table for generating datatables:

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="table table-striped table-condensed table-bordered" id="articles">
 <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Code</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Description</th>
        <th>Created At</th>
        <th>Updated At</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
    <tbody>

    </tbody>
</table>
```

And this is my js:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#articles').dataTable( 
    {
        "bProcessing": true,
        "bServerSide": true,
        "sAjaxSource": "{{URL::to('arayez/getView')}}",
        "aaSorting": [[ 3, "desc" ]],
        "aoColumns": [
        { 'sWidth': '60px' },
        { 'sWidth': '130px', 'sClass': 'center' },
        { 'sWidth': '180px', 'sClass': 'center' },
        { 'sWidth': '60px', 'sClass': 'center' },
        { 'sWidth': '90px', 'sClass': 'center' },
        { 'sWidth': '80px', 'sClass': 'center' },
        { 'sWidth': '80px', 'sClass': 'center' }
        ]
    }
); 
</script>
```

And this is my controller function:

```
class Test extends BaseController
{

    public function getView()
    {
        $result = DB::table('module')->select(array('module.id AS id','module.code','module.name','module.description','module.created_at','module.updated_at','module.user_id'));
        return Datatables::of($result)->make();
    }

}
```

And this is my route:

```
Route::group(
    array('prefix' => 'arayez'), 
    function() {

        Route::get('test', 'arayez\Test@getTest');
        Route::get('getView', array('uses'=>'arayez\Test@getView','as'=>'arayezGetView'));

    }
);
```

And this is the error:

```
{"error":{"type":"Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\FatalErrorException","message":"syntax error, unexpected '['","file":"\/var\/www\/auth\/vendor\/bllim\/datatables\/src\/Bllim\/Datatables\/Datatables.php","line":79}}
```

Is some thing wrong with my code?
Thanks for your helping.

Comment: try check this file: `\/var\/www\/auth\/vendor\/bllim\/datatables\/src\/Bllim\/Datatables\/Datatables.php`at line 79

Comment: Sounds like your PHP version is older than 5.4. What does `php -v` output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the file in the error message ([View on github](https://github.com/bllim/laravel4-datatables-package/blob/master/src/Bllim/Datatables/Datatables.php#L79)) you can see that it's just a short array syntax [added in PHP 5.4](http://php.net/manual/en/migration54.new-features.php). Here's an example:

```
$array = []; // instead of $array = array();
```

This error almost certainly means that your PHP version is older than 5.4. The only way to fix this is to upgrade PHP to at least 5.4. Especially since it's also a requirement for Laravel (I believe since version 4.1)

Comment: I updated my PHP version to 5.4.38 but I got another error like: {"error":{"type":"Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\FatalErrorException","message":"Class 'Illuminate\\Support\\Arr' not found","file":"\/var\/www\/auth\/vendor\/bllim\/datatables\/src\/Bllim\/Datatables\/Datatables.php","line":96}}

Comment: Strange. Try to run `composer dump-autoload`

Comment: I run it but i got the same error, one more thing i should mention it my controller structure is: controller/sub/TestController/function, you thing the problem is this?

Comment: Please run `composer update`. `Illuminate\Support\Arr` is a Laravel framework class that should actually be available...

Comment: first i run composer dump-autoload and then  i run composer update

Comment: Can you check if you have this file in your vendor directory: `vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Arr.php`?

Comment: I am using version 4.1

Comment: Ah I see. 4.1 didn't have that class yet. That error means bllim/datatables requires at least Laravel 4.2. You'll have to upgrade if you want to use that package.

Comment: Sorry i have another question can you see this?: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28859001/laravel-after-composer-update-model-method-call-undefined